# Windows Powershell not opening . Closing after opening . System.AccessViolationException

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, windows-10, powershell-2.0

I was getting this error after i delete some files which were unwanted and also windows suggested me to delete like temp files or windows.old . I tried running my python program its running in cmd , but in vscode terminal its giving me the same error . Also even i opened my powershell then it shows one big exception and closes automatically .

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Management.Automation.AmsiUtils.AmsiNativeMethods.AmsiScanBuffer(IntPtr amsiContext, IntPtr buffer, UInt32 length, String contentName, IntPtr amsiSession, AMSI_RESULT& result)
   at System.Management.Automation.AmsiUtils.ScanContent(String content, String sourceMetadata)
   at System.Management.Automation.CompiledScriptBlockData.PerformSecurityChecks()
   at System.Management.Automation.CompiledScriptBlockData.ReallyCompile(Boolean optimize)
   at System.Management.Automation.CompiledScriptBlockData.CompileUnoptimized()
   at System.Management.Automation.CompiledScriptBlockData.Compile(Boolean optimized)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetCodeToInvoke(Boolean& optimized, ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<InvokeWithPipe>b__0()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Boolean propagateAllExceptionsToTop, List`1 variablesToDefine, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, Object[] args)
   at System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics.CreateModuleImplementation(String name, String path, Object moduleCode, IScriptExtent scriptPosition, SessionState ss, Object privateData, List`1& result, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, Object privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleNamedInManifest(PSModuleInfo parentModule, ModuleSpecification moduleSpecification, String moduleBase, Boolean searchModulePath, String prefix, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean loadTypesFiles, Boolean loadFormatFiles, Object privateData, Boolean& found, String shortModuleName, Nullable`1 manifestLanguageMode)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(String moduleManifestPath, ExternalScriptInfo manifestScriptInfo, Hashtable data, Hashtable localizedData, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version minimumVersion, Version maximumVersion, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 requiredModuleGuid, ImportModuleOptions& options, Boolean& containedErrors)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, Object privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadUsingExtensions(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String moduleName, String fileBaseName, String extension, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadUsingMultiVersionModuleBase(String moduleBase, ImportModuleOptions importModuleOptions, Boolean& found)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadUsingModulePath(PSModuleInfo parentModule, Boolean found, IEnumerable`1 modulePath, String name, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, PSModuleInfo& module)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ImportModule_LocallyViaName(ImportModuleOptions importModuleOptions, String name)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I tried various commands shows on internet , still giving the same error. I also wonders its some memory issue or not . I have sufficient space 20+gb in  C drive , 8gb Ram , Windows 10.

Comment: Why the `powershell-2.0` tag? Windows 10 default is `powershell-5`…